# species identification - re-animated

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

There appear more and more species identification questions. There have been meta-posts before on this issue and the the general opinion seems to be these sort of questions should not be in Biology SE. I think I agree in most cases (exceptions being an infestation of incubators with an unidentified fungus and the likes, relevant stuff that is). But what to do? I have searched for 'ID questions' and none of them seemed to be voted down, or placed on hold.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right now, [species-identification](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/species-identification) questions are on-topic. At [**Gardening & Landscaping** beta](http://gardening.stackexchange.com), we welcome plant, plant-disease, plant-pest, and garden fungus identification questions, but not just any animals or organisms.

Here are three previous posts on this meta about [species-identification](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/species-identification):

- [Species Identification Questions](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181/species-identification-questions)
- [Is it on-topic to ask for the identification of any living organism?](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236/is-it-on-topic-to-ask-for-the-identification-of-any-living-organism)
- [Edible species identification](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335/edible-species-identification)

None of them resulted in the topic being called off.

The thing is, there really isn't an 'identify this organism' SE site, and while GL takes most of them, biology is seen as the best fit for the others. [**The Great Outdoors** beta](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/) had a [discussion](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/548/species-identification) about this recently, and concluded that it was off-topic for their site.

I wouldn't be opposed to having new [plant id questions](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/species-identification+botany) on biology.se get moved to GL, if that's the way everyone here would like to start moving. It does bother me a little that both sites cover the same topic. I [brought it up on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236648/is-it-a-good-idea-to-have-an-identical-topic-plant-identification-on-both-gl-a) at one time.